# Why this program reserves and keeps 2 GB of memory instead of 1 GB?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<char> vc;
typedef std::vector<vc> vvc;

vvc f() {
  const int N = (1 << 15);
  return vvc(N, vc(N)); // 1 GB
}

int main () {
  vvc v; 
  v = f();
  while(true);  // Why 2GB allocated ?
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with both clang -O2 and g++ -O2. Same behavior.

**Edit:** There are multiple ways to fix this code pointed in some of the answers.
But my point is to understand this code. Of course there is a temporary object, but it should disappear at the semicolon and 1GB of memory should be returned to the system. The question intends to ask why it does not happen.

**Edit 2:** The destructor of temporary object is indeed called before semicolon.

Comment: It's the assignment thing. With `std=c++11` it's 1GB.

Comment: Did you tried to reclame the excess memory, for instance launching another instance of this. What happens to first instanced ?

Comment: 4th proccess crashed my machine (8GB ram).

Comment: How are you measuring the memory used?  If you return 1GB to the allocator, that doesn't mean the allocator will necessarily return 1GB to the OS.

Answer (score 4):

You have assignment in your code that we preach against in vain for good reason ;-)

If you used initialization, that allows RVO optimization, and as others experimented it actually seem working too.

With assignment the function return an object, then it must be copied to target and only then nuke the temporary. While with data flow anal it could be possibly optimized, it's a case that hard to catch and considered rare to use. Thus you suffer the performance penalty on top of all the rest.

EDIT: to see that the temporary is indeed nuked at the proper point I suggest using debugger and single-step into functions.  Alternatively look at assy listing. For the abstract machine the dtor call must happen before the next instruction.

However, optimized code uses the 'as if' rule more liberally. If the code has no way to tell the difference, it may postpone it a little, and you may just experience that effect.

C++11 note: in C++11 vector gained another op= that moves from the rvalue. That would cure this particular case, but it will take time till all compilers close the gap and especially all classes gain moving stuff. Pre-11 code looking for moving would use swap() in place of =.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly one of the cases C++11's move semantics solves.

Comment: But why f() frame doesn't get released ? It should happen anyway, even before `while(true);`. I can't see the request for optimization here. Basic dynamic memory semantic should work.

Comment: @CapelliC It probably got released, the operating system just didn’t reclaim it yet.

Comment: @CapelliC, Many allocators never actually release memory to OS, especially for smaller chunks. It can be reclaimed within the process - recreation of vector will not cause raise to 3GB.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: yes, I think that could the be the focus of the question. Otherwise, should be a BIG bug in those compilers.

Comment: @CapelliC: What you are missing is that the object returned from the function lives in the caller's stack frame. The `f()` stack frame is released, but the value returned from `f()` lives in `main`. At any rate, ignoring that, consider that both vectors must be alive at the same time for the copy of the values to succeed. At this point your program consumes 2G of memory, and the allocator will most probably not release that memory back to the OS. If you want to try this out, create your own allocator (C++ allocator) and pass it to the vector, then measure there the memory

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: why do you think I miss that ? The value in main it's a 1 GB size (something more), and that's the point of the question.

Comment: The point of this code is not how to fix it but understand it.

Comment: @CapelliC: "Free" from the program's view and "free" from the operating system's view are not the same. Indeed, in most operating systems, the program *cannot* give that 1GB back to the OS in this situation.

Comment: @CapelliC: No that is what I think you are missing: the maximum size required in `main` is 2Gb not 1Gb. In the context of `main` both the returned value of `f()` and `v` are alive and with the same 1Gb size at the same time. For a brief period of time, but the amount consumed **in** `main` at one point is 2Gb. Similar to `int main() { big1gType obj1; { big1gType obj2; } }`

Comment: Even though temporarly main needs 2GB, in while(true) it should need already 1GB, but it in fact needs 2GB.

Comment: did you look for stuff after 'EDIT:' ?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you're looking at the operating system display of how much memory is allocated to *the process*, and that your compiler doesn't yet support C++11's move assignment.

Therefore what happens is probably the following:

- In your function, you allocate the vector (consuming 1GB of memory).
- Then, in your assignment, that vector is copied (consuming anmother 1GB of memory, which is *adjacent* to the first block).
- After that, the original vector is destroyed. That frees the memory for future allocations in your program, but since that memory is *before* the memory of the retained vector, and for most operating systems the memory allocated to a process must be contiguous, the process can *not* give it back to the operating system.

So the result is that the operating system allocates 2GB to your process, of which 1GB is allocated to the vector, and 1GB is free for future allocation within your program (but not to allocations in another process).

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested on win32, vc7.

Your code allocates 2Gb. If change to this:

```
int main () {
  vvc v = f();
  while(true);
```

It needs only 1Gb.

I suppose the reason - is a copy operation between vectors.

`v = f()` - invokes constructor. Your case - default c'tor and copy (operator `=`) into empty object. Coping needs 2 Gb.

Internal actions of `f()` (creating vector and return) can use [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), and there are no any coping and extra allocating.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: There are multiple ways to fix this code pointed in some of the
>   answers. But my point is to understand this code. Of course there is a
>   temporary object, but it should disappear at the semicolon and 1GB of
>   memory should be returned to the system. The question intends to ask
>   why it does not happen.

On Windows I compiled your test with gcc and ran. And I see that the value of `Private Bytes` is increasing after start of the program and then starts decreasing and then finally stops changing. So on this OS memory is returned to the system. By the way I made use of `Process Explorer` to get information about `Private Bytes`.

I assume you did your test on Linux and on this OS  memory is not returned to the system. If it is not used it is finally moved to a paging area if I am right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the return value will be copied. Than temporary 2 copies of vvc exists.
Each with 2^30 chars (= 1GB)

To my knowledge the compiler is allowed but not required to remove the copy operation

I found this link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: you're right, I think. But see my comment to Balog Pal answer.